# FaceBook Login with IOS

Tags: ios

So here is my quandary:

Ive been asked to build a mobile app that works just as an existing web application works. The web application uses FB login to authenticate users and I need to do the same in ios/Android. The simplest solution is to use a webview and simply view the web app within the native application. This works well until a users logs in with FB. The FB login window pops up and one can log in, but the redirect to the url fails and just a white screen is shown.

My research points me to an issue with the FBSessionDelegate, but Im not sure if that is the issue.

Ideally, Id like to use the sample Hackbook FB app and just have it redirect users to the web app after logging in, but Im a little lost on the authentication path between the two.

Any ideas or assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Facebook's guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/)?

Comment: yes Ive been through it already; it doesn't describe passing the info to a webview.

Comment: Yes an example would be nice; I dont understand how to get the data from the FB login SDK to the uiwebview.

Comment: When you use the FB login SDK, there is no UIWebView involved. Maybe you want to try out the tutorial first? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/ under Authenticate - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/

Comment: Yes Ive worked both of those; its not the issue. The web app Im trying to integrate the login info with is in the uiwebview, while the FB login SDK is native. I need to get the info from one to the other.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do that. If you were able to store a user's login info and transferred it elsewhere, you would be able to use that data to, e.g., login to FB as that user.

Comment: Ok then here is another option. If I simply view the web app in the uiweview and use the existing FB login within the web app, the uiwebview will not return the user back to the site once they have logged in. The user just sees a white screen after logging in. Any ideas? Thanks for your help thus far.